# json array with in array returning error ?bad string

Tags: javascript, php, python, arrays, json

i am parsing my json string file to python and always returning error .
i used online json formatter and validators that also returning error so i want help to make my json correct and tell me error

```
 [{
     "sentence_id": "TR.00001",
     "sentence": {

         "text": "Bill was born 1986.",
         "annotation": {
             (1, "Bill", "bill", "NNP", "B-PERSON"),
             (2, "was", "be", "VBD", "O"),
             (3, "born", "bear", "VBN", "O"),
             (4, "1986", "BIL", "CD", "B-DATE"),
             (5, ".", ".", ".", "O"),

         },
         "relations": {
             "subject": "bill",
             "predicate": "DATE of Birth",
             "object": "1986"
         }
     }
 }, ]
```

the above is my json string you can check online validators or online json format verifier here is the part of json that returns error

```
"annotation": {
    (1, "Bill", "bill", "NNP", "B-PERSON"),
    (2, "was", "be", "VBD", "O"),
    (3, "born", "bear", "VBN", "O"),
    (4, "1986", "BIL", "CD", "B-DATE"),
    (5, ".", ".", ".", "O"),
},
```

so can you please help me in sorting out the trouble of array with in array using json you can use these editors link [link to json editor](http://www.jsoneditoronline.org/)

> expecting property name `,` error in line 8

Comment: This is not a valid json. If the string has pattern, you can implement some logic to convert string to json.

Comment: i really dont know i am using python and have to pass a json file the above is json in training.json file

Comment: your **json** is not valid , take a look [here](http://json.org/) to get more information about the right **json** format .

Comment: expecting property name `,` error in line 8

Comment: @Hamid: Remove the comma on last element of the list, JSON is picky about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your json string file is not proper it have some error ...

1. you missed the key in annotation.
2. your value must be in capital bracket because it is an array.
3. you add extra comma at the end.

   ```
    [
      {
      "sentence_id" : "TR.00001",
      "sentence"  : {

               "text" : "Bill was born 1986.",
               "annotation":{
                              "1": [1,"Bill" , "bill" , "NNP" ,"B-PERSON"],
                              "2":[2, "was" , "be" , "VBD" , "O"],
                              "3": [3 , "born" , "bear" , "VBN", "O"],
                              "4":[4, "1986" , "BIL" , "CD" , "B-DATE"],   
                              "5":[5, "." , "." , ".","O"]
                             }, 
               "relations":{
                             "subject":"bill",
                             "predicate":"DATE of Birth",
                             "object":"1986"
                           }
                }
    }
   ]
   ```

That means your annotation section must be like this:

```
"annotation":{
              "1": [1,"Bill" , "bill" , "NNP" ,"B-PERSON"],
              "2":[2, "was" , "be" , "VBD" , "O"],
              "3": [3 , "born" , "bear" , "VBN", "O"],
              "4":[4, "1986" , "BIL" , "CD" , "B-DATE"],   
              "5":[5, "." , "." , ".","O"]
             },
```

Comment: it is use like this print  `data[0]["sentence"]["relations"]`

Answer (score 2):

JSON doesn't understand tuples, try changing to lists:

```
"annotation": [
    [1, "Bill", "bill", "NNP", "B-PERSON"],
    [2, "was", "be", "VBD", "O"],
    [3, "born", "bear", "VBN", "O"],
    [4, "1986", "BIL", "CD", "B-DATE"],
    [5, ".", ".", ".", "O"]
]
```

You can do `tuple(list)` to convert back to tuples on the other end.

Also, you had an extra comma on `[5, ".", ".", ".", "O"]`, I removed it.